# MAAS deployment of node via MAAS API fails, boot error

Tags: boot, maas

I installed MAAS on my system which consists of a master cluster and four nodes.
For installing I used the autopilot
I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty and MAAS Version 1.9.4+bzr4592-0ubuntu1 (trusty1)

I commissioned all nodes successfully but some nodes refuse to deploy (for testing I just tried to deploy via MAAS API)

two nodes have following problem.
It seems Ubuntu gets installed successfully but after the reboot the system fails to boot form local disc with following error.

On the screen of the deploying node:
TFTP prefix:
Trying to load;
pxelinux.cfg/01-48-0f-cf-44-75-8e
Booting local disk ...
Cannot read Master Boot Record or sector 0
boot:

and here it gets stuck until a timeout.

From machine events of the deploying node from MAAS API:
Node changed status - From 'Deploying' to 'Failed deployment'
TFTP Request - chain.c32
TFTP Request - pxelinux.cfg/01-48-0f-cf-44-75-8e
PXE Request - local boot

I hope sb can help me, Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Are the nodes dell servers and potentially have 'virtual drives'?

Comment: Indeed, these nodes are Dell servers (workstation z840) but each has two physical hard drives and one of them is used for deployment. Moreover I could install openstack landscape on a third Dell node.

Comment: I had some dell servers have something labeled as virtual media in the bios.  It showed up as a hard drive to maas, once I disabled it in the bios the deployment succeeded.  Maybe that applies to you.

Comment: I just realized that these are HP servers not Dell, but anyways, there is nothing labeled as  virtual media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the BIOS configuration, i disabled hard drive booting.
solution: Activate hard drive booting in BIOS options.